# Outlook VBA - open email attachment in appointment and extract sender's email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, extract, attachments

I have over 200 calendar (appointment) entries and all of them contain the original email message as an attachment.  I need to extract the sender's email address from the email attachment in the appointment.

I know how to extract the sender's email address from a MailItem object (`MailItem.SenderEmailAddress`), but I don't know how to access these properties when the email message is now an attachment in an appointment.  The `AppointmentItem` object has an Attachments property, but no other info is available anywhere on how to access any properties in the Attachments object.  Tried AppointmentItem.Attachments.item(1).SenderEmailAddress and got 'object not supported...'

Comment: Did you try "item" (singluar)? It is unclear to me, but "item" may return non-"MailItem Objects" so you may need to use "for each" and then perhaps use "typeof"

Answer (score 0):

You could save the .msg attachment, open as a mailitem then read the mailitem property.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Private Sub saveAndRetrievePropertyOfAttachedMail()

    Dim sPath As String
    
    ' the selected item may not be an AppointmentItem
    Dim oItem As Object
    
    sPath = ""
    
    Set oItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    
    If TypeName(oItem) = "AppointmentItem" Then
        Debug.Print oItem.subject
        
        ' sPath is initially blank
        ' There are risks with public variables.
        ' This is a slightly awkward way to avoid declaring sPath as a public variable
        saveAttachmentsToDriveFolder oItem, sPath
        
        returnPropertiesOfAttachmentInDriveFolder sPath
        
    End If
    
End Sub


Sub saveAttachmentsToDriveFolder(objItem, strPath)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fldTemp As Object
    
    Dim objAtt As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' This is a default folder everyone should have.
    ' You may use another folder.
    ' Kill the files when you are done or delete manually
    Set fldTemp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' TemporaryFolder
    Debug.Print fldTemp
    
    strPath = fldTemp.Path & "\"
    Debug.Print strPath
    
    For Each objAtt In objItem.Attachments
        strFile = strPath & objAtt.FileName
        Debug.Print strFile
        objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
    Next
    
End Sub


Sub returnPropertiesOfAttachmentInDriveFolder(strAttachmentFolder)

Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFiles As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objItem As Object

Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFileSystem.GetFolder(strAttachmentFolder)
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile In objFiles

    If objFileSystem.GetExtensionName(objFile) = "msg" Then
    
        'Open msg file
        Set objItem = Session.OpenSharedItem(objFile.Path)
        Debug.Print objItem.SenderEmailAddress

    End If
Next

End Sub
```